# Looking for the title of a novel about a divine/heavenly being turned into a dog

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I read the book about 19yrs ago (2003/2004). I think it was published by Orion books as I seem to remember a dog-looking-at-stars logo.
In it, a being is maybe banished from the heavens...either was turned into a dog on earth, or just ended up in an already existing dog.

Somewhere, it had the phrase "Your effulgence". I remember because that's the only place I've come across that phrase.

Not sure, but maybe the cover had a mixture of white and light purple.

That's all I can presently remember.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like *[Dogsbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogsbody_(novel))*, by Diana Wynne Jones.

It's from 1975, and I don't specifically remember it using the phrase you mentioned, but the plot outline is pretty specific!

The main character is Sirius (commonly known as the Dog Star), who is banished to Earth in the form of a dog because his enemies think it's ironic and cruel.

Comment: The book is available to borrow with a free account on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dogsbody00jone/mode/2up) - "effulgence" and "effulgency" are both used throughout

Comment: thanks so much guys, I've been looking for it off and on for at least a decade.